# Mesibo Flutter message sending problem in SDK 2.2.0

Tags: flutter, dart, mesibo

In the new SDK of `mesibo_flutter`, when I call `message.send()`, `Mesibo_onMessage()` is triggered but that shouldn't happen as `Mesibo_onMessage()` should only trigger when a message is recieved.

```
Once you send a message, the recipient will receive the message through Mesibo_onMessage
```

I made sure that the Mesibo instance is initialized correctly and the remote profile is correct, but the issue still exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mesibo_onMessage` will be invoked whenever a message is sent or received, regardless of from where in your code you call `message.send()`. This allows all your message listeners to be notified and update the UI or take other actions as needed.

Please refer to the https://docs.mesibo.com/tutorials/get-started/sending-and-receiving-messages/#receiving-messages-message-status-and-updates

> `Mesibo_onMessage` will be invoked whenever a message is sent or received. You can perform various checks to find if the message is incoming or outgoing, real-time or read from the database, group message or one-to-one message, etc

You can use utility functions like `isIncoming()` to check if the message is incoming, outgoing, etc.